# What is the unit measure on a EBS gp3 type?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I am reading https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/pricing/ for ebs volume price. And for `gp3`, it says 3000 IOPS is free. I wonder how much data in size is for 1 IOPS?

For example, if each unit takes 4KB, then 3000 * 4 / 1024 = 12MB, I know it support 12MB per seconds. But how do I know how much each IOPS take in size?

```
General Purpose SSD (gp3) - IOPS    3,000 IOPS free and $0.006/provisioned IOPS-month over 3,000

General Purpose SSD (gp3) - Throughput  125 MB/s free and $0.048/provisioned MB/s-month over 125
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the [FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/ebs/faqs/), EBS IOPS refers to a block of 16 KB.

Comment: If it is 16KB, then 3000 IOPS means `3000 x 16KB/ 1024 = 16MB / sec`? It is far below the free threshold for throughput `125MB/s`. What is the reason to give two free threshold?